# Macroscopic number of qubits (Sсhrödinger cat)

Tags: quantum-computer, schroedingers-cat

I noticed, that current designs if quantum computer [like IBM Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Quantum_Experience), include supercooled chamber to allow matter to be in quantum state.

I thought, if this really required?

To obtain Sсhrödinger cat one need to isolate cat from outer world well, not to cool entire cat to 0.015 kelvins.

So, were there some experiments, where only exterior of chamber was to make qubits work?

Comment: You usually cannot isolate a not cooled system because it radiates.

Comment: We can fill walls with liquid helium or something. We can't observe whether one piece of macroscopic matter was in quantum state, but if several pieces interact, we can notice, that they behave like qubits. We can use even mechanical registers like in old computers, just put each in helium-isolated rooms or chambers!

Comment: If liquid helium interacts with the radiation emitted by the system inside, it counts as the system not being isolated (measurement leading to decoherence).

Comment: It is Schrödinger Cat not Shroedinger Cat! The name of its inventor (author) is Erwin Schrödinger (or Schroedinger if no "ö" is available in your typeset).

Comment: @Anixx if this measurement is isolated, then doesn't matter, because it entangles.

Answer (score 2):

Look, quantum computer is like a car race where all cars start at one point and finish also at one final point. They can take different routes during the race, but desirably should all finish at the same place.

Now, you suggest rising the temperature. It is like putting drunk drivers in each car. The cars would deviate from the route and never reach finish point.

You suggest surround the system with liquid helium. Okay, this is like surrounding your racing town with deep forest. If the drivers are drunk they will lose themselves in the forest and will not reach the finish. After the experiment is over (say, the bridges to your island unlocked), the cars will leave the island without reaching the finish point.

This is because liquid helium is a complicated thermodynamic system, and you cannot recohere it once it interacted with your quantum processor without taking care about each particle in it. After experiment is over, it will interact with the outsiude world, which has the same effect as the interaction during the experiment being conducted (you should isolate the qubits you are interested in not only during the experiment, but in the future as well because any measurement in the future will collapse the wave function in the past). Only after all reached the finish, you can unlock bridges to your island.